# Generating $n \times n \times \cdots \times n$ table

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I want to write a function that automatically create a $n \times n \times \cdots \times n$ (all $D$ $n$'s) multiplication table with $D$ as the argument of the function, which is automatically generating the following code

`Table[i1 i2 i3 ... iD, {i1,1,n}, ...,{iD,1,n}]`

how to generate
`{i1,1,n}, ...,{iD,1,n}` to put into the `Table` function? I can generate 
`{ {i1,1,n}, ...,{iD,1,n}}` but can't get rid of the outer most `{}` to put into `Table`.

Comment: It's not necessarily "good form", but I always use `Apply[Sequence,...]` for this.

Comment: Or you can use `##` (which is entirely equivalent to Daniel's suggestion): `Table[(* stuff *), ##] & @@ {{i1, 1, n}, ...,{iD, 1, n}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say you can generate

```
 {{i1,1,n}, ...,{iD,1,n}}
```

then just use

```
Table@@{i1 ... id,{i1,1,n}, ...,{iD,1,n}}
```

Look up Apply in the help system to get some ideas how this works

Answer (score 6):

`Array[]` is much more suitable for your task if all you wish is a multiplication table. Using Henrik's example:

```
With[{n = 5, d = 6}, Array[Times, ConstantArray[n, d]]]
```

Comment: (Still no computer, so this is from my *gedanken Mathematica*.)

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 5;
d = 6;
a = Outer[Times, ##] & @@ ConstantArray[Range[n], d];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the `ConstantArray` detour? I'm looking for something like `Tuples[Range[n], d]` but generating a nested list instead of a flat list.

Comment: What's your problem with `ConstantArray`?

Comment: It just seems a bit inefficient to construct the `ConstantArray[Range[n], d]` containing a lot of redundant information. Considering how `Tuples[Range[n], d]` gets away with less redundancy, I was wondering if there's a more elegant way: something like `Tuples[Range[n], d]` but directly constructing a nested list. @JM's answer is more concise but is limited to `Range[n]` as a list of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is close to what I'd be looking for, but not quite:

```
ArrayReshape[Times @@@ Tuples[Range[n], d], ConstantArray[n, d]]
```

Ideally this should be possible without `ArrayReshape`ing, and instead constructing the nested list directly and similarly to `Tuples`. Unfortunately `Tuples` is limited to constructing flat lists of tuples, not nested lists.

Advantages of this solution:

- doesn't need to construct the redundant `ConstantArray[Range[n], d]` list that @HenrikSchumacher's solution requires (for what it's worth)
- works with any list of elements, not just `Range[n]`, as opposed to @JM's solution

Disadvantages of this solution:

- looks more clumsy than either of the aforementioned

Comment: Consider `ent = Range[n]; Nest[Outer[Times, ent, #] &, 1, d]` if you are quite uncomfortable with the use of `ConstantArray[]`.

Comment: Getting closer, thanks!